# Wordpress: post date as a link to archive of posts with the same date

Tags: wordpress

This is a simple and straightforward question. How do I set the post date as a link to archive of posts with the same date?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? StackOverflow isn't a 'code this for me' site (that's probably why somebody down-voted your question).

Comment: I tried get_day_link().

Comment: Ok I figured it out. <a href="<?php echo get_day_link(get_post_time('Y'), get_post_time('m'), get_post_time('j'));  ?>" class="entry-date"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></a>

Answer (score 10):

I figured it out.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_day_link(get_post_time('Y'), get_post_time('m'), get_post_time('j'));  ?>" class="entry-date"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></a>
```

Comment: This might be the solution I'm looking for. Will have to make it into a shortcode. Will report back